# Dummy query to make recursive EFCore 2 properties load

Tags: c#, loading, ef-core-2.0

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get my recursive EFCore objects to load all their grandparents/grandchildren and I can't decide if I'm being rubbish or I'm working around features which aren't working as desired.

A Link has a Category, which exists in a hierarchy of other Categories (the data structure works fine)

```
Link link = FP.Links.Include(a=>a.Transaction.Account.Home)
                    .Include(a=>a.Category)
                    .ThenInclude(b=>b.parent)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(a=>a.TransId==_transId && 
                    a.Transaction.Account.Home==_authHome)
 .FirstOrDefault();
```

When I look at the Link.Category.parent.parent it is null. It always seems to load the first couple of levels above, when I pull back a link whose category has more than 2 parents, it eventually gives me a null.

I've tried various SO answers which have guided me to use includes (which feels clunky) and the latest talks about .AsEnumerable(). I've tried FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault().

I've got as far as: Loading in EFCore 2 is far from done, and that 'fixing up' is a thing. So, I tried adding:

```
List<Category> CL= FP.Categories.Where(a=>a.home==_authHome).ToList();
```

before the previous query and it works.

I have three questions:

1) Have I correctly interpreted that this forces my DBContext to have already loaded the data I need, and so it has access when I re-query?

2) Am I leaving myself open to this NOT working in some circumstances which testing wouldn't show me?

3) Is there any less inane way to make this same thing work?
(I may want link.Category.parent.parent.parent.(n).parent to all be accessible)

---

and a question that, knowing the rules of SO, I'll phrase rhetorically:

4) Is there any world in which this is desirable from a debugging/coding point of view????

---

Classes:

```
public class Link
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("Transaction")]
    public int TransId { get; set; }

    public DateTime effectiveDt { get; set; }
    public bool isRefund { get; set; }
    public int transactionRole { get; set; } 

    public int setBy { get; set; }

    public string transactionComment { get; set; }

    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public partial class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int categoryType { get; set; } //0=Normal, 1=Savings, 2=Loan

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Category parent { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Summary> summaries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> children { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Link { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Budget> Budget { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Home home { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What are your entity classes?

Comment: added - the rest of my data access works fine, so I don't think I've done anything wrong.....

Comment: (1) Are you sure the objects you are checking actually have `parent.parent.parent...` (2) No need to `Include` parent at all. Try replacing `AsEnumerable()` with `ToList` to make sure EF navigation property fixup is complete at the time you apply parent filter.

Comment: Changed to the below, doesn't work, I get a single parent (and there are 3)
        
    Link link = FP.Links.Include(a=>a.Transaction.Account.Home)
                        .Include(a=>a.Category)
                        .ToList()
                        .Where(a=>a.TransId==_transId && a.Transaction.Account.Home==_authHome)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Oops, missed the fact that your query starts with `Link`. Since there is no recursive query support in LINQ (not only EF Core), practically the only way is to preload the `Categories` before materializing the actual query.

Comment: Ah. Ok. So it's never going to resolve itself. How annoying

Comment: Would a non-linq version of it work better?